# Health effect of worm in Guava

Tags: botany, entomology

I ate a ripe guava, rife enough to be broken with hand, i later saw that it has white worms with one black end crawling inside it, are these worm harmful, i had unripe guava of same batch though most of them had small black spot inside, but no worm crawling, what are these crawling worms, were they present in guava from unripe stage or infected only after ripening ?

Comment: Without photos it's going to be hard to even get close to an identification.

Comment: That *worm* inside the ripe guava is just the larva of a fly. I don't know where you are, but in South America the most common genus is *Anastrepha*. It doesn't make any harm eating a guava with them... well, except for the poor larva, which will die.

Comment: in  biology, human parasites never lay their eggs on fruit. a fruit and a human digestive system are not the same environment. the only other possible danger is chemicals in fruit dwelling animals. flies aren't very dangerous. but there are parastic flies like tsetse and the bot fly.

Comment: re fly biology: it would be interesting to see if the fruit is attracting the fly on purpose.  I am sure that the presence of the fly larva (meat!) increases the protein value of the fruit.  Maybe having larvae in it makes the fruit a tastier treat for an animal which can eat it and spread the seeds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a safe bet that a "worm" as you describe in a ripe guava or any other ripe sweet fruit is a [fruit fly](https://entomology.ca.uky.edu/ef621).

[image: fruit fly larvae]
from http://www.greenharvest.com.au/PestControlOrganic/Information/FruitFlyControl.html

Fruit flies are attracted to any ripe sweet fruit.  They are also attracted to vinegar and alcohol - both produced by yeast in and on the fruit, which is the high protein food that the fruit flies are really after in the fruit.

from 
http://homeguides.sfgate.com/treat-fruit-flies-guavas-30550.html

> When ripe, guavas emit a pungent, musky odor that attracts fruit
>   flies. Fruit flies lay their eggs beneath the fruit's skin, and the
>   maggots feed on the flesh. The damage causes guavas to rot. Fruit fly
>   infestations often spread quickly, but prompt treatment can get
>   populations under control.

The fly large actually speed the rotting of the fruit by moving yeast around on their bodies.